# Difference between "engage" and "hire"

Tags: differences, verbs, american-english, british-english

For example,
"We decide to *engage* a lawyer for the case."
"We decide to *hire* a lawyer for the case."

Is *engage* used particularly in British English?  Do speakers of American English use *engage* in such examples?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, [*engage*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engage) is really not all that common when it comes to hiring people. Just use [*hire;*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hire) its primary definition is more applicable to the situation than *engage*. It is interesting to note that the definition of *hire* includes the word *engage*. I think that hiring someone is a more specific form of engagement, and if you're looking to achieve clarity, then *hire* is your best bet.

I'm fairly certain that the definitions of these two words have little variation between British English and American English, so this answer most likely applies to both.

**Edit:** Colin Fine has informed me that this does *not* necessarily apply to British English.

Comment: No, it does not apply to British English, except insofar as US expressions have become common in recent decades. Up to thirty or forty years ago, the only things you "hired" in Britain were inanimate objects: tools, clothing, cars. The general word for people is "employ", with "engage" a somewhat more formal (or elegant) variant. There isn't really a colloquial word for it, and phrases such as "give a job to" are used.

Comment: @ColinFine My apologies then. I shall edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Take on" is another British expression for it.

Comment: @ColinFine We say that here, but it's informal.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the words given by the NOAD are the following:

- hire: employ for a short time to do a particular job
- engage: arrange to employ or hire someone

Similar definitions are given by the Merriam and Webster, which gives the following definitions:

#### hire

- to engage the temporary use of something for a fixed sum
- to grant the personal services of somebody, or the temporary use of somebody for a fixed sum

#### engage

- to arrange to obtain the use or services of somebody

Looking at the CoCA and BNC for sentences containing "engage a lawyer" and "hire a lawyer" I get the following results:

[image: screenshot]